# Как организовать различные переходы в зависимости от индекса страницы PageViewController

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, ios7

Здравствуйте!

Я продолжаю свое изучение obj c. И у меня возник вопрос. Я сделал 3 страницы в PageViewController, на каждой из них расположен TableView. Хочется сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ячейку на каждой отдельной странице переход был организован в свой ViewController. Ума не приложу, как это можно сделать, подскажите, буду рад, а если и пример подобной организации в каком-либо проекте, буду безумно рад.

На данный момент при переходе с любой из страниц у меня осуществляется переход в один единственный ViewController.

Comment: @Gool12222, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если используется `storyboard`, прокидываем от исходного `UIViewController` c зажатым ctrl segue к тому, на который нужно перейти, выставляем настройки переход segue type = push/show, identifier = "GoDetails1". Переход прокидываем не от ячейки таблицы или кнопки или еще какого контрола, а от самого котроллера (желтого квадрата вверху). Дальше реализуем метод UITableViewDelegate, что-то типа того (пишу на swift, на Obj-C будет тоже самое):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
           case (_, 0): performSegueWithIdentifier("GoDetails\(indexPath.row)", sender: self)
           default: println("No segue setup for indexPath \(indexPath)")
     }
}
```

Нужно просто трекать, какая ячейка была выбрана и вызывать соответственно `performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_identifier", sender: AnyObject!)` с нужным identifier.